# Дилемма с авторизацией

Tags: битрикс

Я хочу создать авторизацию на Битрикс. Я могу сделать это с помощью ajax и phpmyadmin, но после просмотра видео на эту тему я запутался и растерялся. Там говорится о том, что нужно использовать компонент и с этим компонентом я могу сделать авторизацию. НО. Где хранится пользовательская информация? Где я могу увидеть логин и пароль? И теперь я полностью запутался. Мне нужен
совет от опытного программиста. КАК СОЗДАТЬ АВТОРИЗАЦИЮ НА БИТРИКСЕ И ВИДЕТЬ ИХ ЛОГИН И ПАРОЛЬ?

Comment: Данные пользователей хранятся в таблице `b_user`.

Answer (score 3):

компонент регистрации 
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/sluzhebnie/user/main_register.php
компонент авторизации 
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/sluzhebnie/user/system_auth_form.php

Эти два компонента используются для регистрации и авторизации пользователя.

Информация по пользователям находится в административной части 
http://prntscr.com/odk2um
Советую почитать про события которые происходят при регистрации если Вам необходимо как-то модифицировать данные 
 https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeuserregister.php